# How to query mongodb with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to query a MongoDB database using java driver.
 For example, these are two documents of *mycoll* collection:

```
{
"_id":"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d73100",
"person_id":"100", 
"name":"UFlQsAWmgp",
"surname":"ohJTiGRqsM",
"place":"UtXVBKoajo",
"age":90
}
{
"_id":"4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d73101",
"person_id":"101", 
"name":"AosStuizVj",
"surname":"BCYcWKDTdu",
"place":"jRlEszdLOw",
"age":62
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all people with 5 years old using Java driver:

```
try
        { 
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
            String database = "test";
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(database);
            System.out.println("*****Connect to database successfully*****");
            String collection="mycoll";
            MongoCollection coll = db.getCollection(collection);
            System.out.println("*****Connect to collection " + "\"" + collection + "\" successfully******");    

            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("age", 5);
            DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
```

This code does not work. Eclipse does not recogize

```
coll.find(....)
```

as you can see:
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `coll.find(query)`? In your image it says `collection.find(query)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `collection` variable is a `String`. You should be using `find(...)` with the `coll` variable.

The devil is clearly in the details of the compiler error -- it states "*...is undefined for the type **String***"